# Expand/Collapse table data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've started a deep dive in to HTML + CSS + JS for the past couple of days and I'm curious to know is it possible to expand and collapse rest of the table data if I click my first table data on my table row.

I've tried myself using multiple combinations but couldn't succeed so I wanted to understand is it really possible or I have to improve further :)

Thanks!

https://jsfiddle.net/p9mtqhm7/553/

If I click on say - AUSDe451 or AUSDe441, rest of the corresponding columns should be either expand or collapse[`i.e LAMP   6.93817139 & 51_REGALIA 456.352`] should expand/collapse if I click - `AUSDe451`]

Comment: are you trying to group rows? and collapse and expand that group

Comment: you want to expand collapse cols & rows ?

Comment: @snjynegi : If I click on NAME column (or those values - AUSDe451 or AUSDe441) its corresponding columns should collapse or expand

Comment: @rvz: Only columns, say click first NAME column and it expands/collapses the rest of the columns on that row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your click handler is a bit wrong!

When you're handling clicks on the `.server-name` element, `$(this)` inside the function refers to the item that has been clicked, in this case the `.server-name` table row.

When you run `$(this).find(...)`, you're looking for child elements of the table row, which do not exist. So rather than use `$(this).find(...)`, you should probably be looking elsewhere in the DOM.

Also, you seem to be searching for `span` elements, which don't exist anywhere in your HTML markup, so that part of the function will never return anything anyway.

Comment: If I add `$('.members').click(function(){
   $(this).find('span').text(function(_, value){return value=='-'?'+':'-'});
    $(this).nextUntil('td.members').slideToggle(500, function(){
    });
});` its not giving the expected result

https://jsfiddle.net/p9mtqhm7/559/

Comment: Your `$(this).nextUntil('td.members')` statement won't work properly, because there is no td element with a class of 'members'

Comment: I'd recommend spending some time with the jQuery docs for `nextUntil()` - this function will return all sibling elements until the next matched element:
https://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/

Comment: Actually, it's your answer that's *"a bit wrong"*, not the click handler. You answered without fully understanding the question. OP wants a click on first column to expand/collapse the rest of the columns on that row. Read the last part of the question carefully.

Comment: @Chris: As @ Andrei Gheorghiu  said, click on first column to expand/collapse the rest of the columns on that row.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu sorry, I don't agree - the click handler _is_ wrong. The click handler has been attached to the wrong element: the server name table row, not the cells that the OP is interested in. This should arguably be the first place to start, and was the first thing I mentioned - the other items are additional errors that I felt were worth pointing out. Read the code in the JSFiddle carefully.

Comment: @Rookie1999 Just to make it clearer, your click handler has been attached to the `.server-name` element. This is wrong. If you want to handle clicks on a particular cell (e.g. the AUSDe451 cell in your question) then you should give those cells a class and attach the click handler there instead. You will then find it easier to select the following cells to show/hide.

Comment: It's not wrong. He's just missing the +/- span inside the header row (which is what the first command should toggle) see it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/p9mtqhm7/560/). The expanding/collapsing is done by `.nextUntil()` which effectively toggles everything until next `tr.server-name`. The question is about how to collapse/expand columns inside a row on a item/item basis.

Comment: Ok, I see where the confusion is. I'd assumed that the JS in the fiddle that the OP had posted was his existing attempt to solve the problem, whereas it is actually just an unrelated part of the same page.

Comment: @Rookie1999 if you want to handle a click on the first cell element, you could use `$('.members td:first-child').click(...)` and then go from there. Inside the click handler, `$(this).siblings()` will then select the other cells in that row for you to process.

Comment: @Chris : You're right, that JS in the fiddle is my existing state and I'm trying to fix it as asked in the question - click on first column to expand/collapse the rest of the columns corresponding for every NAME value.

Ex, If I click on AUSDe451 , its corresponind VALUE & INT columns should be collpased. there are 2 rows corresponding for `AUSDe451` and those two should be collpased - `LAMP 6.93817139 and 
51_REGALIA 456.352`

Hopefully I have made myself clear

Comment: @Chris: Yes I tried using the siblings method, since I'm very new I'm unable to construct the exact syntax.. Could you please help me here.. like a complete syntax would be helpful

Comment: `$('.members td:first-child').click(function() {
 $(this).siblings().toggle();
});`
will work if you just want to show/hide the cells for that particular row. If you want to show/hide the entire columns for that table then it's a little more tricky!

Comment: @Chris: `show/hide the entire columns for that table` is the one I'm looking :) ..For particular row, I'm able to show/hide using `td class`. I'm failing when I'm trying for corresponding table :( .. Thanks a lot for your suggestions/ inputs and help here

Comment: Try this: `$('.members td:first-child').click(function() {
 $(this).closest('table').find('td').not(':first-child').toggle();
});`

Comment: @Chris: Beauty !! Worked like charm !!

Comment: Hooray! Good stuff, glad it helped. When you get a moment it's worth checking out those jQuery methods (`closest`, `not` etc.) so you understand what's going on as they're really useful.

Comment: @Chris: sorry but its collapsing other tables too :)

Comment: @Chris: My apologies for not checking thoroughly :(

Comment: The code will collapse everything within the same table as the cell that is clicked. In your markup, you've got a single table containing two headers, which isn't great practice - you should ideally have a separate table for each header, using `thead` and `tbody` to group the separate parts. In your case I would end one table and start another one before each subsequent header.

Comment: @Chris: Gotcha, that helped a lot !!